# Vector of vectors as efficient data structure; alternatives to std::vector<std::vector<someType>>

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, vector

I'm looking for data structure where I can stores multiple vectors in one vector without risking fragmentation or any performance issues.

Now doing this

```
std::vector< std::vector<SomeType> > myMultiVector;
```

would help, but for my understanding the memory gets fragmented because obviously every vector within *myMultiVector* will not lie in a contiguous space, because of its allocation scheme.

This is not for creating arrays where I know the dimensions or sizes from the start. The sizes are dynamic in all directions. What I want is a structure like that one, in which the allocated size is contiguous. I want to be able to do something like **push_back()** and **resize()** on the vector of vectors and every vector itself. The size of the vectors should be able to differ.

I have been taking a look at Boost::Multiarray. Seems promising, but don't want an array, I want something where dyanmic. I'm still not sure, though I can change sizes in the dimensions if it does that by an efficient way. So maybe Boost::Multiarray is the answer for that.

I also have been thinking about using **std::multimap** or even **std::unordered_multimap** and use the key as index, because of the interal sorting and hashing I'm not sure if it the right structure though the allocation space should be contiguous.

Using *std::vector< std::vector > myMultiVector;* works for what I need but I feel there is a missed oportunity for optimization.

**What other Alternatives do you know which could help providing a more efficient vector of vectors?** Let me know :-)

NOTE: I know the question is quite similar to others asked here. I'm only asking for alternatives not quite for the solution of a particular problem.

Comment: Modelling as a contiguous block with a vector of pointers denoting the start of the "outer" vectors, seems like the way to go. I've used something on these lines in the past. I'd set aside at least two months to get this container correct though.

Comment: This seems to be going to be closed as too broad, so I'm not going to write a full answer. tl;dr you can implement a continuous vector of vectors using a single vector the size of all subvectors combined and a separate vector for iterators that point to the starts of each subvector. It's not all roses, though. The catch is that you want to do push_back for each subvector. That is very efficient for regular vector of vectors (amortized constant complexity), but expensive for the flat vector (linear in the total size of vectors).

Comment: The vector of vectors seems like a reasonable compromise, until you have  identified a specific operation that is the bottleneck. Then you can optimize for that, if needed. Like most things in computing, it's a trade-off between several factors (time, space, complexity, programmer effort), and there is no silver bullet that gives you a Single Best. If there were, we would only have one type of container!

Comment: Your data structure cannot be both contiguous *and* allow arbitrary resizing. Do you see the problem here?

Comment: There's a mistake in my comment. You cannot use iterators, but must use indices of subvectors, since the iterators will invalidate when the vector grows.

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like the different things you want exclude each other. If you want to have a size-flexibility in each of the subvectors and at the same time have all the data nicely aligned in the memory you are basically forced to reallocate memory for all vectors and do a lot of copying each time you change the size of any of the subvectors. Thus probably it's a better idea to stay with the `std::vector< std::vector<SomeType> >`. If you need to do a lot of efficient operations with a fixed size of the vectors between every resize operation, you could think of creating an intermediate array into which you copy all your data.

You should also think about whether your concerns about performance have an effect in practice. Unless you notice that using `std::vector< std::vector<SomeType> >` does actually influence your performance significantly you should maybe not worry about it.

So to directly answer your question: I think there probably is no *better* data type for your needs, because the one you suggested is already totally fine.

Answer (score 4):

If you're careful about using it, you could always implement a 1D vector as a 2D one using functors:

```
template <typename T>
class Vector2D : public std::vector<T>
{
protected:
    unsigned _width;
public:
    unsigned width() {return _width;}
    void setWidth(unsigned i) {width = i;}

    T& operator()(int x, int y) {
        return this->operator[](x + _width * y);
    }

    Vector2D(unsigned newWidth = 10) : std::vector<T>(), _width(newWidth) {}
};
```

Which allows you to do things like:

```
int main() {
    Vector2D<int> vec(10);
    vec.resize(100, 0);

    vec(6, 7) = 3;

    int some_number = vec(6, 7);

    cout << some_number: //Output: 3
}
```

The advantage of this approach is that the data is contiguous, yet can be manipulated with 2-dimensional semantics.

Comment: what's wrong with this answer? obviously more could be done to give the container more features but this solution is in line with many of the comments on the question itself

Answer (score 0):

`std::multimap` / `std::unordered_multimap` will certainly not do what you want.  Each individual `SomeType` will be in it's own allocation (much worse than a vector of vectors).

I don't think you will find a pre-built type that does what you want - you are going to have write it yourself (possibly by wrapping a single `std::vector`, and then providing smart iterators which understand the range of this particular vector).  Note that `my_magic.front().push_back(...)` will have to insert into the middle of your backing vector, and shuffle everything up (although vector::insert will do the shuffling for you).

Personally, I would be surprised if it was worth it.

Answer (score -2):

I would suggest using your own container. I am going to give you an abstract Idea:

```
class MyOwn2D{
MyOwn2D(int rows,int cols):rows(rows),cols(cols),data(std::vector<SomeType>(rows*cols){}
SomeType& get_element(int i,int j){
    return data[i*rows+j];
}
private:
    int rows,cols
    std::vector<SomeType> data;
};
```

The previous example is so dummy. You need something much better with `operators overloading` and you may need a `proxy` to do `[][] operator` (to more like `2D array`). So, I was just proposing the idea of it. Good Luck!